# Merge multiple workbook into single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have zone wise data in different excel. I want to create a macro to merge all excel files in a new worksheet.

I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
    Sub CopyBooks()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Const path As String = "C:\Corporate Competition\Excel\merge\"
    Dim file As Variant

    Dim currentSheets As Long
    currentSheets = destinationWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    file = Dir(path & "**.xls**")

    While file <> ""
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(path & file)
        For Each sourceWorksheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            sourceWorksheet.Copy
            lCopyLastRow = sourceWorksheet.Cells(sourceWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lDestLastRow = currentSheets.Cells(ThisWorkbook.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            sourceWorksheet.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
            Next
        sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I want all files to append one after another. Also, a column name to indicate the zone name/excel file name will be of great help.

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error? Do you get unexpected output? etc...

Comment: lDestLastRow = currentSheets.Cells(ThisWorkbook.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row. I am getting an error for this line, member not found.

Comment: `currentSheets` is a number. Do you mean to use the last sheet in the workbook to find the destination last row? You would want something like `Worksheets(currentSheets).Cells(...` instead if so.  Also, FYI, you can remove the `Thisworkbook` in front of `Rows.Count`, as all workbooks will have the same total row count.

Comment: I am copying data from one excel using lCopyLastRow and finding the first empty row in the destination file to copy there.